# Race condition between nested applications of (define ...)?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, race-condition

Using DrRacket, on both linux and Mac OS, the following code gives this error

```
*: expects type <number> as 1st argument, given #<undefined>
```

but if I uncomment the (newline) at the beginning of the procedure definition, it works fine, yielding the expected value, 9.

```
#lang r5rs

(define (quadr x y)
        ;(newline)
        (define xx (* x x))
        (define yy (* y y))
        (define xxyy (* xx yy))
        (+ xx yy xxyy))

(display (quadr 1 2))
(newline)
```

Is this a bug in Racket's scheme interpreter, or is the language specified so that the nested invocations of (define ...) may happen out of order?  If the latter is the case, where can I find the relevant bit of the language specification?

As an aside, I am very aware of the "let" construct and know that this is not the recommended way to define such a procedure.  Still, I didn't expect this error.

Comment: It's not necessarily recommended to use `let` over internal definitions. Racket programmers especially tend to prefer internal definitions, since `#lang racket` supports internal definitions in more syntactic forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the relevant [link](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.2) to the R5RS specification explaining the behavior of internal definitions. Notice that in section §5.2.2 is stated that:

> ... it must be possible to evaluate each `<expression>` of every internal definition in a `<body>` without assigning or referring to the value of any `<variable>` being defined.

In other words, you can't count on a correct behavior if you `define` values that depend on previously `define`d values within the same internal definition. Use `let*` for this:

```
(define (quadr x y)
  (let* ((xx   (* x x))
         (yy   (* y y))
         (xxyy (* xx yy)))
    (+ xx yy xxyy)))
```

Or a bit more verbose, using a couple of nested `let`s:

```
(define (quadr x y)
  (let ((xx (* x x))
        (yy (* y y)))
    (let ((xxyy (* xx yy)))
      (+ xx yy xxyy))))
```

It's very peculiar that inserting a `(newline)` causes the variable definition to work for this example, but when you're dealing with undefined behavior, anything can happen. As a side note, if I use `#lang racket` instead of `#lang r5rs`, the original code works for me without the extra `(newline)`.

Comment: Re your last comment: R5RS has `letrec` semantics for internal definitions, and R6RS and R7RS have `letrec*` semantics. This is why you see a different behaviour depending on whether you're using `#lang r5rs`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Did racket really change their language to conform with `R6RS` before going their own way?

Comment: @Sylwester many of the racket developers were deeply involved with the development of R6RS, so it's not too surprising that R6RS and Racket agree in many ways.